# What general equipment is needed to 'explore' circuits?

Tags: circuit-analysis, test-equipment

I'm new to circuit design and I want to start using some equipment to analyze some circuits I have to see how they work. Right now all I have is a multi-meter, a JTAG SAM/AVR programmer, a 5 Volt power supply, and some intermediate soldering equipment (reflow oven, vacuum part picker, iron, etc).

This does not seem like enough to find out how some circuits work, as it's currently difficult to see what's happening by only reading multi meters and hex files.

What are some general standard pieces of equipment that would be required to analyze low-medium complexity circuits? I'm not looking for specific recommendations, rather I'm looking for tool types that I can use for the given purpose of circuit analysis.

Comment: Expect this to be closed.  That said, an oscilloscope is a good thing to have.

Comment: @JRE why would it be closed?

Comment: Too broad, opinion, recommendations.

Comment: You need an oscilloscope unless the circuits are dead simple and only have DC signals.

Comment: For digital signals, communication protocols (UART, I2C, SPI, etc.) a logic analyzer can be pretty handy too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of a small handful things you might need, depending on what you're doing:

1. An oscilloscope - essential if you want to examine waveforms and compare voltage vs time.  Needed for timing circuits, clocks, oscillators, or anything of that nature.  Could also be needed if you're doing RF stuff, but scopes that can measure at the higher RF frequencies get crazy expensive quick.  But a decent 100mhz scope with a 1G/s sampling rate can be had for < $400.00.
2. A frequency counter - May be slightly redundant with the oscilloscope, but a good standalone frequency counter can be a very useful tool. Again, this mainly needed when you're working with any kind of timing/clock signal or anything emitting a constant frequency.
3. A function generator - so you can deliver "known good" inputs to a circuit and then compare the output with what's expected.  Say you have a circuit that expects a square wave at 5hz as the input, but it's not behaving.  You think your input is good, but want a way to sanity check. You can feed your circuit the expected input using a function generator and see if it works. If so, you know your input is off somehow. If not, the problem is elsewhere.
4. A logic analyzer - this can be pretty inexpensive for a basic analyzer.  A Bus Pirate will work, or you can just run software on a Beaglebone Black and make it a Logic Analyzer, optionally with a cape that does level conversion if needed.  There are dedicated benchtop logic analyzers, but they tend to be expensive and more specialized.  Some oscilloscopes also have optional add-ons that let them double up as a logic analyzer as well.
5. The other "main" piece of test equipment I can think of is a spectrum analyzer, but I would consider that much more specialized and not something you're likely to need for basic circuit exploration.

Edit:

6. A high quality lab power supply with current limiting.  Current limiting because sometimes you aren't sure your circuit is right and you don't want to risk accidentally dumping a gazillion amps into it.  Up to 12 volts covers probably the bulk of use cases a hobbyist will run into, but if you're getting a quality lab power supply, it'll probably do 30V or better anyway.

That said, if a proper lab power supply isn't available and you can get by without current limiting, you can get a lot of mileage out of a generic ATX PC power supply.  Those give you 12V, -12V, 5V, and 3.3V out of the box.  I use one with a homemade circuit board with an LM317 adjustable voltage regulator for times when I need 9V or 6V or something else.

Comment: Good list. As he has a 5V psu, I'd add a +/-12V (or adjustable) supply if he's looking at more than a few analog circuits

Comment: Good point. Added that.

Comment: Thanks for the good answer. I wanted to accept it before it got closed on me.

Answer (score 1):

This may be too broad a question, but I'll try to answer.

For analog and mixed signal circuits- more-or-less in order of daily usefulness- a lab power supply with multiple outputs and current limiting, an oscilloscope, function generator (to inject signals), spectrum analyzer.

The  cost will largely be determined by the bandwidth you want to work with (and the voltages/currents for the power supply) rather than the complexity of the circuit. Working with mains or microwaves often requires a whole different set of equipment and skill set.

Of course this is in addition to whatever you need to work with the digital circuitry- programmers, emulators, logic analyzers, sniffers and so on.

Answer (score 0):

On the job, I'm a troubleshooter of industrial PC's and fieldbus communication gadgets... in a small company. It feels like the last area of electronics where lower-end equipment and practical hacks possibly get you anywhere :-) For my fairly simple needs, I find the following equipment pretty useful:

I have a relatively inexpensive dual-channel USB oscilloscope, the M595 from a company called ETC. It sports 1 GSps (500 MSps if both channels are used) and about 300-350 MHz analog bandwidth (-3 dB). 32k samples memory sounds like not very much, compared to real oscilloscopes that cost 10 times the money :-) but does get many jobs done just fine. The screen size is only limited by your PC's display resolution, and you can take screenshots just by Alt+PrintScreen... 
It's got a simple spectrum analyzer app included, which obviously only works up to 500 MHz and is also limited by the 'scope's 8bit resolution - but combined with automatic range switching (effectively AGC) it's not all that bad. The spectrum analyzer thing has helped me debug some intermediate frequency stuff in GPS receivers, can show you a DSL line handshake etc. I guess I could see strong FM radio transmitters :-) I also used it once or twice to "look around" for strong EMI from PSU's or VFD's...

A USB scope is a little stupid in that if you need to travel, the whole setup for basic oscilloscope operation involves a laptop, the USB scopey box, an AC/12V mains adaptor (as USB power is not enough), and a USB cable, and the whole thing becomes a little unwieldy, compared to a portable battery-powered all-in-one oscilloscope. Around here, I can see some OWON models around 1 GSps and 200 MHz analog BW that seem to work pretty well, in terms of bandwidth and ranges comparable to my M595. Also, a battery-based scope that's all plastic on the outside might provide a crude way to measure mains-level stuff or generally wherever you need the scope's reference GND to be isolated from local protective earth. Note that these cheap broadband 'scopes do not have their inputs truly galvanically isolated (per definition I'd almost say). Also, the OWON that I had the pleasure to quickly test-drive, seemd to have the controls slightly more complicated to tweak/operate than the full-screen app of the ETC M595 where everything is just a click away - but that may be just my bias, based on everyday past experience with the latter device.

Note that an important part of an oscilloscope are some plausible probes. I use passive probes with a built-in selectable divider, 1:1 or 1:10, 200 MHz bandwidth. While you're at it, you may want to buy a 50 Ohm pass-through terminator or two (in case you wanted to measure some half-serious RF stuff).

A scope of this category can show you a lot in switch-mode regulators, reflections and reference ground mischiefs in RS485, obviously any kind of simple TTL logic. Note that these scopes are a higher league than entry-level handheld scopemeters by Fluke (those have other uses: good for mains sinewave stuff). And, the scopes I mentioned above are not fast enough to show you DVI/HDMI/PCI-e and other such fast modern busses, or fast ripples in the VRM secondaries of modern CPU's (hinting at bad capacitors).

If you put together a simple pulse generator with impedance-matched output (something simple out of 74AC/ACT logic gates), you get a simple small-signal time-domain reflectometer for testing coax and twisted-pair transmission lines.
If you build that, buy a handful of coax connector conversion plugs and terminators and make some RJ45 socket adaptors to attach to your generator (and an RJ45 terminator plug is useful too).

In my private life, I've used a DVB-T tuner (USB dongle) based on the Realtek RTL2832U combined with a software called RTLSDR Scanner to adjust some TV antenna systems in the family. The scanner is pretty slow, compared to a professional overview spectrum analyzer, but did get the job done several times. What I'm still missing is some cheap way to scan the WiFi spectrum at 2.4 and 5 GHz (there are modified WiFi dongles that can do that, but my need has not yet been accute enough for me to buy one).

An oscilloscope and a spectrum analyzer are really useful basic equipment. They make all the difference between guessing and actually seeing what's going on (and you should expect to be surprised, at times, what's gazing back at you from the wires.) To me, watching something misbehave on the outside, and then attaching an oscilloscope, feels like watching the sea level from outside, and then taking the scuba glasses and diving in...